# Parent/Append/Prepend arrangement

Tags: jquery, append, clone, parent, prepend

On a doubleclick, a new clone of the clicked element is created. It's imperative that this new clone is prepended to the parent wrapper. However, this becomes problematic as there is an element above the clone targets. The clones that are produced are placed above this misc element. I need to have the clones placed above the original, but below this misc element.

```
<div id="wrapper">

----> <img class="clone_target Copy"/> *prepend places them here.

<span class="misc_element"></span>

----> <img class="clone_target Copy"/> *the clones should go here.

<img class="clone_target"/>

</div>
```

Comment: Is `.clone_target` supposed to be a child of `.misc_element`?

Comment: oh, no, missed the closing tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
$('.clone_target').dblclick(function (e) {
    $(this).before($(this).clone().addClass('copy'));
});
```

To limit the number of copies made,

```
var MAX_CLONES = 30;
$('.clone_target').dblclick(function (e) {
    if ($(this).prevUntil('.misc_element').length < MAX_CLONES) {
        $(this).before($(this).clone().addClass('copy'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$(".clone_target").click(function() {
    var $clone = $(this).clone(true);
    $(this).parent().find(".misc_element:last").after($clone);
});
```

[You can try it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/SfSZm/2/)

See http://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: Thanks! It worked. How would i limit the number of copies made?